# Call lhs2tex from LateX

Tags: shell-escape, lhs2tex

The lhs2tex tool is a very awesome code formatter, especially for Haskell, but it usually expects to be run as a preprocessor. Now I really like being able to just `pdflatex` my files, especially when I collaborate with others.

Is there a way to make latex itself write out the content of the code blocks, run lhs2tex on them and read back the result, transparently?

Comment: This is exactly what the minted package does (using the pygmentize code formatter) you should be able to copy that, just changing the name of the external program call

Comment: I also asked with the `lhs2tex` upstream: https://github.com/kosmikus/lhs2tex/issues/47